# if phpinfo() in the code,the web page will be redirect to data:image/png;base64

Tags: centos6.5, php

In my VPS's localhost/127.0.0.1, it's okay to reach.

[image]

While on my computer it looks like:

[image]

When I `echo` or write the html in php file, it will looked as same as the vps's localhost.

Can somebody tell me why?
Does anybody encounter this problem before？

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: `data:image/png;base64` refers to the PHP logo and zend engine images which are embedded in the `phpinfo()` page (maybe others too). That's supposed to be there. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

my problem: i can't open the php file page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB76f.jpg) which include the phpinfo() function outside the vps.

reason:  the WAF isolate my request because phpinfo() steal server information